# Distribution over variable-sized input

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Given a base bitmap **s** and a set of possible sucessor bitmaps **s1**, ..., **sN**, how can I train a TensorFlow graph to compute a probability distribution over these sucessors ?

Every bitmap **sK** could be processed as a single input by the same network to give a real value representing it likelihood, which could then at this point be mapped trough a softmax layer to give a probability distribution.

However, doing this by hand wouldn't allow to use backpropagation and implemented optimizers, and it's not even guaranted that it would accept variable lenght input and outputs.

Is this even possible ? Input and Output tensors seems to have necessarly a fixed size appart over the batch dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a base bitmap **s** and given that you want to model the distribution of the sequence **s1**, **s2**, ..., **sN**.

This can be achieved using a sequence labeling RNN model, where you want to model the probability distribution of the sequence **s1**, **s2**, ..., **sN**. But to condition on **s**, you can concatenate the feature vector of **s** to every input in the sequence. So at time-step **t**, the input vector to the RNN will be the concatenation of feature vector for **s_t** and **s** and after the softmax, the expected output should be **s_t+1** (i.e. the loss should be such that. eg. Cross-entropy loss can be used).

Variable-length sequences can very well be used. Tensorflow always as many dimensions of the placeholder to be *None*, i.e. of variable size during running the graph. So along with variable batch-size you can very well have variable length sequences.

Comment: Well, to explain it better I have a bitmap s and s1, ..., sN a variable length sequence of expected outputs (where N is variable for each input). Train and test sets consist of these inputs along with a correct output s* that is one of the expected outputs.

Comment: Also, I would like to use convolutional layers because inputs are basically images.

Comment: I think applying the same convnet on each bitmap and then a softmax on the concatened outputs would give a relevant result but I'm not sure it would allow to use tensorflow's optimizers. Would RNN be relevant here? Can it be used with conv layers?

Comment: Yes. RNN would be relevant here. It can be used with conv layers and tensorflow optimizers would work.